# Reduce the number of elements in the vector

Tags: python, numpy, math, vector, scipy

I am working on a project in Python and faced with a problem: I have many vectors (one-dimensional arrays) with different numbers of elements, and I need to bring them to the same standard.
For example, I have:

```
a = [37, 26, 35, 22, 12, 7] 
b = [24, 17, 85, 24, 45, 71, 31]
c = [87, 20]
```

I want to fit this in arrays with the same length:

```
a1 = [xxx, yyy, zzz]
b1 = [xxx, yyy, zzz]
c1 = [xxx, yyy, zzz]
```

I am not very good at math and I have no idea how it can be done. I tried using the function:

```
y = [1, 1, 1]
a1 = scipy.signal.fftconvolve(y, a, mode='same', axes=None)
>> a1 ([98, 83, 69])
```

But it seems to me that this is not exactly what I need and she is performing some other actions. Maybe I'm wrong and what I used for this is exactly what is needed.

Pls, don't shame me for being stupid.

Comment: You can pad the arrays with zeros until they are the same length. For example: add one zero to vector a and add 5 zeros to vector c. Now all arrays should have the same size of vector b (size of 7)

Comment: @VRComp this is not the way i want to do, just because i need to create linear model, based on this data. Too many values ​​will spoil the regression.

Comment: I am probably misunderstanding. Can you re-phrase the question and give a sample output of what you want based on the sample vectors (a, b, c)?

Comment: @VRComp The only thing I have thought of so far is to sort the values ​​in descending order and leave only the extreme and central ones. And then return in the appropriate order.

Comment: What makes you believe that you can reduce the dimensions of your arrays without losing information? Also we have no clue what the data is nor how you want to process it afterwards.